# Viruses in Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: partitioning, games, skype, malware

My Ubuntu 14.04 system has been hit by a virus, I am 100% sure this is a virus, let me tell you what happened.

So, I was playing Minecraft in my desktop with some friends on Skype, then my Skype logs out due to a Disk I/O error. So, I reboot my PC, and it boots up. So, since I run a gaming server, I decide to modify the files, but first I start Skype, and my best friend is messaging me and is mad at me for reasons I don't know, so I go onto the server he is usually on and try to confront him, and he just leaves the game! I was mad at him back and then wanted to download this file, unfortunutely it didn't let me because I had no space left. So, I go into the system disks, and what do you know! I have 40GB space left! I thought it was just a bug, so, I open GParted, and try to resize this other partition to make it smaller and see if it fixes the problem, but I couldn't change the numbers as it kept resetting to what it had before, so I try moving the box where you usually resize it, and it doesn't even budge! I then modify the files to prepare to delete this big directory I have backed up, and do it, but when I restart the computer to delete the directory, the computer boots up to a black screen! How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you edit your question and clarify the problem? I agree, this does not really sound like a virus to me.

Comment: "I am 100% sure this is a virus" um, no you're not.  A positive virus scan would an indicator of a virus.  What you have is a bunch of symptoms that indicate disk faults.  Do you know what a virus is?

Comment: @neon_overload I know, a virus is harmful code that does damage to the computer's software, however I didn't know the symptoms of disk faults.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your disk is probably failing. You probably don't have a virus.

You can check your drive SMART data using `smartctl -H /dev/sda`, but if Ubuntu told you there's a disk error you should believe it.

Start copying your data to another drive. Stop using the drive for any other purpose in case you're destroying your documents.